# KML & Google Maps: Problem to load value from <ExtendedData> into the pop-up window

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, kml

I create a Google Dynamic Map (Maps JavaScript API) with points loaded from the KML file. I need to show only "NTS_Text" attribute from ExtendedData.

I struggle with pop-up window and showing one *SimpleData* value from *ExtendedData*.

This is part of my KML file:

**KML Schema**

```
<Schema name="Adresy_web_kml" id="Adresy_web_kml_ID">
    <SimpleField name="ogc_fid" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="kod" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="cislodomov" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="cisloorien" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="cisloori_1" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="psc" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="stavebniob" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="ulicekod" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="NTS_buildi" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="NTS_type_i" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="NTS_techno" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="NTS_Text" type="string"><displayName><![CDATA[<i>popis</i>]]></displayName></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="ruian stavebniobjekty_typstavebnihoobjektukod" type="int"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
```

**KMl style**

```
<Style id="globema_style">
  <IconStyle>
    <scale>1</scale>
    <Icon>
        <href>https://sites.google.com/site/karolinakmlhosting/kml-files/kolecko_7px.png</href>
    </Icon>
   </IconStyle>

<BalloonStyle>       
  <text>
    <![CDATA[Informace o výstavbě: $[Adresy_web_kml_ID/NTS_Text]  ]]>
  </text>     
</BalloonStyle>

</Style>
```

**One single Placemark**

```
<Placemark><styleUrl>#globema_style</styleUrl>
<ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Adresy_web_kml_ID">
    <SimpleData name="ogc_fid">341</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="kod">72899409</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="cislodomov">1358</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="psc">33401</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="stavebniob">78228484</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="ulicekod">1038231</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="NTS_buildi">1358</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="NTS_type_i">10</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="NTS_techno">13</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="NTS_Text">Výstavba 2020 - 2022. Kontaktujte nás pro další informace.</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="ruian stavebniobjekty_typstavebnihoobjektukod">1</SimpleData>
</SchemaData></ExtendedData>
  <Point><coordinates>13.3353507611569,49.5811128320989</coordinates></Point>
```

**This is the result**
[Info window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6zu7.jpg)

Any idea how to format the kml file to be able to show the data in the map?
Thank you.

Comment: <SchemaData> and <SimpleData> within <ExtendedData> are not supported KML elements by the Maps JS API.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#supported-elements

Answer (score 0):

Those replacements aren't (currently) supported by [KmlLayer](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#overview).
From [the documentation](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#supported-elements):

> `<ExtendedData>`  partially   untyped `<Data>` only, no **`<SimpleData>`** or **`<Schema>`**, and **entity replacements of the form $[dataName] are not supported.**

You could possibly extend a third-party KML parser to support that ([geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) kmz branch supports some replacements (Data, but not SimpleData; [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20200220_ExtendedDataF.kml))

[image: screenshot of map using geoxml3 and Data tags]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found a solution and I simply put the text into <description> tag.